# Delete the "Phone" part of a contact whilst keeping the "Google" part?

Tags: contacts, htc-sense, htc-hero

HTC Hero with HTC Sense - Android 2.1.

Contacts can be either stored on "SIM", "Google" or "Phone". Many contacts are duplicated on "Phone", but I want them all in "Google" so I can manage easily. I've managed to copy all "Phone" to "Google", but now want to remove from "Phone".
However, whenever I try to delete a contact (e.g. Bob), it deletes Bob from "Phone" AND "Google". I can't find a way to delete Bob from just "Phone" - any ideas? Factory reset is throwing the baby out with the bathwater, and not a great technical solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question - here's a different approach to achieve this (Google-only contacts)

- Ensure all required Android contacts are synced to Google
- Export the contacts to CSV on a computer
- Delete all contacts from the Android (that'll be both "Phone" and "Google")
- Import the contacts from CSV to Google
- Google will then sync to the phone

Kind of obvious in hindsight. Hope this benefits the community in some way!

Comment: I'm confused, does HTC Hero not come with stock Contact apps? The stock Contact apps should sync two ways between Gmail address book and Android's address book (i.e. if you add contact in Google, it should show in phone, and if you add contact in Android, it should show in Gmail contact; all without any more work)

Answer (score 3):

This is the procedure I use on my phone; hope there's something similar for yours:

On the Samsung Vibrant (also Android 2.1) when I open the contact, there's an entry for **Linked Contacts** that shows both the Google contact and the Phone contact (and a SIM contact if you have one).  If you select that, you get a new screen showing the linked contacts; each one has a <kbd>-</kbd> button next to it to unlink it from the others on that screen.  Go back to the main contacts list and you should have two entries for that contact -- delete the one with the phone icon next to it.

Comment: Yes - unlinking the two contacts, and then deleting the Phone one works. Unfortunately HTC Sense's "Contacts" app doesn't seem to have icons (so I have to change the view), and I have to unlink every contact manually. Thanks for the tip though!